# Regular Expression For Only Digits & A Single Dot

Tags: javascript, regex

i need regular expression for :

one or two digits then . and one or two digits.

Valid Expressions :

```
1
1.5
11.5
```

Invalid Expression :

```
0..
0.
11.
```

I have tried using the following Regex.

```
^[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$
```

but it does not validate when i enter 12. or something like that.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Arijit,it is not working when i enter two digits and a single dot only not any single digit after dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `12.` is not covered. Neither by your specification (dot, followed by one or two digits), nor your examples, nor your regex (in fact, it's one of your examples for an *invalid* expression). If you enter a dot, then there have to follow digits because both the dot and the trailing digits are in the same group.

You could make the digits optional, too:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

That is, a dot may also be followed by zero digits instead of just one or two.

In JavaScript `\d` and `[0-9]` are equivalent, by the way, so you can shorten it a bit:

```
^\d{1,2}(\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Comment: Hi Joey,the regex should not allow 12. or something like that.

Comment: In that case your regex is in fact correct and there should be no problem. Whatever you're observing, it has to be somewhere else.

Comment: The regex is working fine, really. The code around it might not be. Type `/^[0-9]{1,2}([.][0-9]{1,2})?$/.test('12.')` into the JS console and it will return `false`.

Comment: But now it is accepting 0.0 which is invalid in my case.

Comment: Why is it invalid? Your description of what is valid and not includes `0.0`.